# Using .after jQuery to add a msg only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I have been playing around with adding a class to a DOM element when the email value entered into my email form field does not pass my regex test. It will add my message below my field as desired but will do it multiple times, stacking up multiple msg's. The code below does that:

```
if(emailFault==true){
            //error exists
            $("#email").addClass("error");
            $( "#email" ).after( "<span>" + msgEmail + "</span>" );
            //alert(msg);
            event.preventDefault();
        }
```

This is some code that I attempted to use but breaks my form completely, but should help give an idea of what I am trying to do:

```
if(emailFault==true) && (!$("#email").hasClass("error")){
            //error exists
            $("#email").addClass("error");
            $( "#email" ).after( "<span>" + msgEmail + "</span>" );
            //alert(msg);
            event.preventDefault();
        }
```

Comment: Your `if` syntax is incorrect. You don't need the second `if` keyword. `if (emailFault && !$("#email").hasClass("error")) {`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thankyou, very new to js so appreciate the help. Made the change but it still breaks my validation so I will keep playing around with it, cheers.

Comment: You've removed the second `if` with an edit, but now have incorrect brackets.  Don't close brackets before `&&` then open again - the entire check/clause after `if` needs to be in a bracket (you can have extra brackets inside).   `if (...complete clause...) {`

Comment: The way statements work, your original code would have worked if you removed the `&&` - it would be one `if`, that passes so checks the 2nd `if` `if(emailFault==true) if (!$("#email").hasClass("error")){ }` is the equivalent of `if(emailFault==true) { if (!$("#email").hasClass("error")){ } }` (which looks better with proper line breaks an in a comment).  But still can be clearer with the `&&` inside the `if` brackets.

Comment: @freedomn-m Thanks for the clarification, appreciate it. Just beginning js and really struggling with the syntax looking forward to the day it becomes second nature! hahaha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&&` between two if statements seems like a problem to me. Try

```
if(emailFault==true && !$("#email").hasClass("error")) {

        //error exists
        $("#email").addClass("error");
        $( "#email" ).after( "<span>" + msgEmail + "</span>" );
        //alert(msg);
        event.preventDefault();
        
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Dropped the if but syntax was still incorrect because I had the parenthesis after true, noticed that from the code you shared, cheers